# Preload Images for Photoswipe Gallery

Tags: ejs, photoswipe

So I have an array of images I want to load into a gallery using Photoswipe, but I'm having trouble predefining the image width and height. Specifically, I think I need to preload the images

Here's my JS to render the page, here I'm defining slides and listing as a local variable for the ejs page to use:

```js
    var sizeOf = require('image-size');
    var url = require('url');
    var http = require('http');

    var slideshow = [];

    for(var i = 0; i < listing.listing_images.length; i++) {
        var image = listing.listing_images[i];
        var width, height = 0;
        var imgUrl = image.url;
        var options = url.parse(imgUrl);

        http.get(options, function (response) {
            var chunks = [];
            response.on('data', function (chunk) {
                chunks.push(chunk);
            }).on('end', function() {
                var buffer = Buffer.concat(chunks);
                **height = sizeOf(buffer).height;
                width = sizeOf(buffer).width;**
            });
        });
        var item = {
            src: image.url,
            h: height,
            w: width
        };


        slideshow.push(item);
    }


    res.render('example.ejs', {
        listing: listing,
        slides: slideshow
    });
```

And here is the script in the ejs page :

```js
<% var slides = locals.slides %>
<script>
$('document').ready(function() {
    var pswpElement = document.querySelectorAll('.pswp')[0];

    // build items array using slideshow variable 
    var items = <%- JSON.stringify(slides) %>;
    console.log(items);

    // grab image

    if (items.length > 0) {
        // define options (if needed)
        var options = {
            // optionName: 'option value'
            // for example:
            index: 0 // start at first slide
        };

        // Initializes and opens PhotoSwipe
        var gallery = new PhotoSwipe( pswpElement, PhotoSwipeUI_Default, items, options);
        gallery.init();

    }

</script>
```

Basically what's happening is the array of photoswipe items is being passed in fine, but the width and height aren't set until photoswipe initializes and triggers the img to load. So the images don't show, because their height and width aren't set yet.

Is there a way to trigger the loading of the images in the slideshow array so that the width & height are set before passing to Photoswipe? I've also tried seeing if I could just set them initially to 0, and then try and update the height and width later and try to force photoswipe to reload, but photoswipe doesn't recognize the image's new height/width.

Sorry if any of this is unclear/muddled with ejs nonsense, feel free to ask anything and I'd love to clarify.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Ended up solving this leveraging the API:

```
gallery.listen('gettingData', function(index, item) {
        // index - index of a slide that was loaded
        // item - slide object
        var img = new Image();
        img.src = item.src;
        item.h = img.height;
        item.w = img.width;
    });

    gallery.invalidateCurrItems();
// updates the content of slides
    gallery.updateSize(true);
```

If anyone happens to be reading this and there's a better way to read image size without creating a new img, or optimize this I'd love suggestions. :)